# Change color tr in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

```
@foreach(var item in model){
    <tr id ="nameoftr">
    <td>
    asd
    </td>
    @if(item.num > 5)
    {
    <script>document.getElementById('nameoftr').className = 'blinkAction';</script>
    }
    </tr>
    }
```

i tried like this to change class of the tr but only the first row affected but there are many >5 rows.
i tried the if block under the tr block the result was same. How can i change the all of the row's class.
How can i solve this?

Comment: Id should be unique you cannot use same id for mutiple elements .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the script tag for assigning a class. You can do it as below.

```
@foreach (var item in model)
{
    var className = item.num > 5 ? "blinkAction" : string.Empty;
    <tr id="nameoftr" class="@className">
        <td>
            asd
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```